# finite sum with combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

I have two finite sum with combinatorics:$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 4^{n-k} \binom{2n-k+1}{k}$$ and $$g(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 4^{n-k}\binom{2n-k}{k}$$

I tried several methods but have no clue how to derive that $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=2n+1$. Can anybody help me?

Any hint is appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $g(n)$, see Problem 10F in Van Lint and Wilson's *A Course in Combinatorics*. One approach is to note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2n+1) x^{2n} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n+1}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x^2}\right) = \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$
and then show that
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) x^{2n}$ reduces to the same expression, as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) x^{2n} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n(−1)^k 4^{n−k}\binom{2n−k}{k} x^{2n}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (−1)^k x^{2k} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n−k}{k} 4^{n-k}x^{2n-2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n−k}{2n-2k} (2x)^{2n-2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{2r+k}{2r} (2x)^{2r}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1+(-1)^r}{2}\binom{r+k}{r} (2x)^r\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{r+k}{r} (2x)^r + \sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{r+k}{r} (-2x)^r\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \left(\frac{1}{(1-2x)^{k+1}} + \frac{1}{(1+2x)^{k+1}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-2x)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-x^2}{1-2x}\right)^k + \frac{1}{2(1+2x)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-x^2}{1+2x}\right)^k\\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-2x)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x^2}{1-2x}} + \frac{1}{2(1+2x)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x^2}{1+2x}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-2x+x^2)} + \frac{1}{2(1+2x+x^2)}\\
&= \frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}
\end{align}

An alternative combinatorial proof (coloring the integers 1 to $2n$ red or blue such that if $i$ is red then $i-1$ is not blue) uses the inclusion-exclusion principle.

For $f(n)$, one approach is to note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^n = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1}\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2},$$
so $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^{2n} = \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2},$$
and then show that
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) x^{2n}$ reduces to the same expression, as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) x^{2n} &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (−1)^k 4^{n−k}\binom{2n−k+1}{k} x^{2n}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (−1)^k x^{2k} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n−k+1}{k} 4^{n-k}x^{2n-2k}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom{2n−k+1}{2n-2k+1} (2x)^{2n-2k}\\
&= \frac{1}{2x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{2r+k+1}{2r+1} (2x)^{2r+1}\\
&= \frac{1}{2x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^r}{2}\binom{r+k}{r} (2x)^r\\
&= \frac{1}{4x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \left(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{r+k}{r} (2x)^r - \sum_{r=0}^\infty \binom{r+k}{r} (-2x)^r\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{4x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (−x^2)^k \left(\frac{1}{(1-2x)^{k+1}} - \frac{1}{(1+2x)^{k+1}}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{4x(1-2x)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-x^2}{1-2x}\right)^k - \frac{1}{4x(1+2x)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{-x^2}{1+2x}\right)^k\\
&= \frac{1}{4x(1-2x)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x^2}{1-2x}} - \frac{1}{4x(1+2x)}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{-x^2}{1+2x}}\\
&= \frac{1}{4x(1-2x+x^2)} - \frac{1}{4x(1+2x+x^2)}\\
&= \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Do you have any snapshot about the solution of Problem 10F? Greatly appreciate that!

Comment: I added some hints just now.

Comment: I added complete proofs for both $f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=2n+1$.

Answer (score 4):

For the second one, we start as follows:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 4^{n-k} {2n-k\choose k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 4^{n-k} {2n-k\choose 2n-2k}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 4^{n-k} [z^{2n-2k}] (1+z)^{2n-k}
\\ = [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k 4^{n-k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}.$$

Now when  $k\gt n$  we get  zero contribution  due to  the coefficient
extractor $[z^{2n}]$  and the  factor $z^{2k}$,  so this  enforces the
range of the sum and we may continue with

$$[z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{k\ge 0} (-1)^k 4^{n-k} z^{2k} (1+z)^{-k}
\\ = 4^n [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n} \frac{1}{1+z^2/(1+z)/4}
\\ = 4^{n+1} [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{4+4z+z^2}
= 4^{n+1} [z^{2n}] (1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(z+2)^2}.$$

This is

$$4^{n+1} \;\underset{z}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}}
(1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(z+2)^2}.$$

We introduce $z/(1+z)=w$ so that $z  = w/(1-w)$ and $dz = 1/(1-w)^2 \;
dw,$ to obtain

$$4^{n+1} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}}
\frac{1}{(w/(1-w)+2)^2} \frac{1}{(1-w)^2}
\\ = 4^{n+1} \;\underset{w}{\mathrm{res}}\; \frac{1}{w^{2n+1}}
\frac{1}{(2-w)^2}
\\ = 4^{n+1} [w^{2n}] \frac{1}{(2-w)^2}
= 4^{n} [w^{2n}] \frac{1}{(1-w/2)^2}
= 4^n (2n+1) \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \\ = 2n+1.$$

**Remark.** This can also be done  using the fact that residues sum to
zero, which starting  from the residue in $z$ we  see that the residue
at infinity is zero, so our sum is

$$- 4^{n+1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=-2} \frac{1}{z^{2n+1}}
(1+z)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(z+2)^2}
\\ = - 4^{n+1}
\left.\left(\frac{1}{z^{2n+1}}
(1+z)^{2n+1}\right)'\right|_{z=-2}
\\ = - 4^{n+1}
\left.\left(-\frac{2n+1}{z^{2n+2}}
(1+z)^{2n+1}+ \frac{(2n+1)}{z^{2n+1}}
(1+z)^{2n}\right)
\right|_{z=-2}
\\ = (2n+1) \times 4^{n+1}
\left(\frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{(-2)^{2n+2}}
- \frac{(-1)^{2n}}{(-2)^{2n+1}}\right)
\\ = (2n+1) \times 2^{2n+2}
\left(- \frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}
+ \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right)
= 2n+1.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry that I am no idea what is $[z]$ from the first line to the second line. By the way, I guess there might be some generic method that is applicable to deal with both $h(n)$ and $g(n)$, or any recursive solution....Do you have any idea on that track?

Comment: The $[z^n]$ indicates the coefficient of $z^n$ in the generating function that follows.